# How to use PHPSpreadsheet classes inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress, phpspreadsheet

I have created a AJAX function that runs on a click event on the front end. Inside this function I want to be able to generate a XLS Spreadsheet but I am unable to do this inside the function. I believe its to do with me declaring the use statements outside the function maybe the function is unable to access the classes? I tried declairing them inside the function and I got this error;

```
syntax error, unexpected 'use'
```

Doe's anyone have a solution for this? Here's my code;

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_campaign', 'email_campaign');
add_action('wp_ajax_campaign', 'email_campaign');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

function email_campaign(){
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');

    die();
}
```

here is how I call my function;

```
$('#campaign_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            action: 'campaign'
        },
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What php version do you have on server? Have you tried to put the use / import of other classes at the top of the file? Below namespace?

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you calling the function?

Comment: @blues Oh that error doesn't matter now. It was because I was was declaring use inside my function. I now know that it must be declared in the outermost scope of the file

Comment: @niklaz I'm running php 7. I have no idea what your asking in your second question sorry

Answer (score 1):

Modify Your Code as :

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

function email_campaign(){
    $path = dirname(__DIR__).'/sheets';
    $fileName = 'hello_world.xlsx';

    $spreadsheet = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
    $writer = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($path.'/'.$fileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the XLSX speadsheet isn't been generated

Comment: Spreadsheet is generated but code must define where to save the file full path and also better to generate file name without space.

Comment: How do I declare where to save the file? Usually it just automatically saves to my root dir on the server.

Comment: @Reece Modified code will save to <parent dir of script>/sheets/hello_world.xlsx
You can modify path as you want, mentioned is just for example.

Comment: POST https://website.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 I'm getting this error in the console

Comment: @Reece Check the path you are generating and is it writable by your code.